# Startup program: bring to foreground

Tags: windows-7, gui

We have several computers used as music players.
The player program is launched from the startup folder. The program runs in full screen. Users can then scan a barcode to listen the desired music.

But the program's window is not on the foreground (but it is the only visible thing on the screen, so this SEEMS ok). So when the user scans the barcode, the program doesn't have focus. It doesn't get the data from the barcode reader (which emulates a keyboard).

To put it on the foreground, a simple mouse click inside the window could do the job, but there is no mouse or keyboard available to the user. Only a barcode scanner.

How can we put this window in the foreground without modifying the program?

Comment: What have you attempted to do?

Comment: Are there other items in your start up folder? Use [AutoRuns](http://superuser.com/a/529764/50173) to view all other possible start up items. There must be one that is launched after your music player and so steels the focus

Comment: This sounds like a kiosk or similar, was this a custom developed application?

Comment: @nixda if he is using windows couldn't he just use msconfig to see the startup?

Comment: @ColeBusby Windows has many different places where autostart items can be places. MSconfig doesn't show all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you can't find a better method, just use the following Powershell code:

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
"@
sleep -sec 2
$h = (Get-Process firefox).MainWindowHandle
[void] [Tricks]::SetForegroundWindow($h)
```

It's from [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556872/how-to-set-foreground-window-from-powershell-event-subscriber-action).